# Localizing Region-Based Active Contours

Tags: matlab

I am working in Lankton paper [Localizing Region-Based Active Contours](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2796112/) that has to do with localized active contours and especially in mean separation energy part. I am stuck in a point that I cannot understand how this is implemented. The equation (17) in this paper is as below.
[image]

I downloaded the matlab code for this part from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30284-active-contours-implementation---test-platform-gui/content/Activeontours/localized_seg.m). The equation (17) in this paper is transformed into matlab code as follows

```
dphidt = F./max(abs(F)) + λ*curvature
```

where F is

```
F = -((u-v).*((I(idx)-u)./Ain+(I(idx)-v)./Aout));
```

where Ain=Au and Aout=Aυ.

Can anyone help me with the mathematics and explain how (17) is transformed to this code part.How the first part of (17)

```
((I(idx)-u)^2/Ain-(I(idx)-v)^2/Aout)
```

transformed to

```
 -((u-v).*((I(idx)-u)./Ain+(I(idx)-v)./Aout));
```

Thank you